# How to get category count using group by in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Hi i am create one query for get category count in which some period of time date. in my database i have 3 table first is category , subcategory , subcategoryfollow. now i want to who user follow sub category then i want to count for category. for ex user A follow 3 sub category for category 1 then user B follow same 3 sub category for category 1 then i want category 1 for count is getting 2 like this want result in the query but don't getting this type result.

Here is my query =>

```
select count(*) as Count,categroyName from categroy s inner join 
(
select SS.categroyId from subcategory ss 
inner join 
( 
    select count(*) as count,subcategoryId from subcategoryfollow SSS
    WHERE SSS.IsFollowed = 1  and CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime as date) >=  CAST('2017-07-21' as date)
    AND CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime as date) <= CAST('2017-07-22' as date)
    group by SSS.subcategoryId,SSS.UserId
   ) as tab on tab.subcategoryId = ss.subcategoryId group by SS.subcategoryId
  )  as res on res.categroyId = s.categroyId where s.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY res.categroyId,categroyName
```

This is my current o/p =>

```
Count | categroyName
 1       playing 
 1       Reading
```

This is my exepected o/p =>

```
Count | categroyName
2       playing 
1       Reading
```

Table categroy data =>

```
categroyId | Name 
 1           playing      
 2           Reading
```

Table subcategory data =>

```
subcategoryId | categroyId | Name
 1                1           cricket
 2                1           football
 3                1           wallyball 
 4                2           bibal
 5               2           story
```

Table subcategoryfollow data =>

```
Id | UserId | subcategoryId | IsFollowed | InsertDateTime
 1      10          1                1          2017-07-21 05:57:07.347
 2      10          2                1          2017-07-21 05:56:02.347
 3      10          3                1          2017-07-21 05:58:01.347
 4      11          1                1          2017-07-21 05:59:08.347
 5      11          2                1          2017-07-21 05:60:01.347
 6      11          3                1          2017-07-21 05:61:06.347
 7      13          4                1          2017-07-21 05:61:06.347
 8      13          5                1          2017-07-21 05:61:06.347
```

this is my query and result. now in my table playing category store 3 sub category like cricket,football,wallyball now 2 user follow this 3 sub category so i want count 2 for the palying category. so please any one know how can do that.

Comment: Please provide some sample table data too..

Comment: @Wanderer ok i will do

Comment: Show sample data please.  I'm guessing there is a much easier way of writing your query.  I won't even attempt an answer now.

Comment: @Wanderer and Tim Biegeleisen i have edit my question please give me some hint

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have edit my question please give me some hint how can do tat

Comment: @Wanderer it's possible for the get category count with this table data? can you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle to understand your question fully. Are you looking for something like below query.

```
SELECT c.Name, COUNT( DISTINCT UserId ) AS Cnt
FROM subcategory AS sc
    INNER JOIN subcategoryfollow AS scf ON sc.subcategoryId = scf.subcategoryId
    INNER JOIN categroy AS s ON sc.categroyId = s.categroyId
WHERE scf.IsFollowed = 1  and CAST(scf.InsertDateTime as date) >=  CAST('2017-07-21' as date)
    AND CAST(scf.InsertDateTime as date) <= CAST('2017-07-22' as date)
    AND s.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY sc.categroyId, c.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data and your expected result, try with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT ucount, category FROM (
SELECT COUNT(F.userid) AS ucount,C.name AS category 
FROM Category AS C 
INNER JOIN SubCategory AS S ON C.categoryid = S.categoryid
INNER JOIN SubCategoryFollow AS F ON S.subcategoryid = F.subcategoryid
GROUP BY S.name,C.name) AS UserCount
GROUP BY ucount,category;
```